# Form getting submitted twice even after disabling the submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am working on code igniter PHP wherein my form was initially getting submitted multiple times. I had 2 submit buttons, on clicking the first button a popup opens and the second submit button is on the popup. On form submit I disable both the buttons. But still I had a multiple enter in my database.

I tried refreshing the page to check if it submits again, but that doesn't happen. Have checked on different browsers for issues too but all in vain.

Following are the snippets, can't add the entire form since it is too big. The form is divided into sections with next and previous buttons and on the last section we display the submit button and the popup.

```
<form name="ques_response" id="ques_response" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>data/insert" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

These are the various buttons:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-blue btn-back" id="prev-button">Previous</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="final-button">Submit</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-blue btn-next" id="next-button">Next</button>
<input type="submit" id="popup-final-button" name="Submit" value="Final" class="final_submit btn btn-blue btn-save" >
```

And this is where I disable the buttons:

```
$("#ques_response").submit(function(){
    $('#final-button').attr("disabled",true);
    $('#popup-final-button').attr("disabled",true);
});
```

What I really need to know is why even after disabling the buttons the form gets submitted twice. I am more keen in recreating this issue if there is a way. Also if i can do something to avoid this. Any server side handling too.

Thanks

Comment: Can you reproduce a double submit yourself? The double entries could come from user or robots blocking or ignoring you script

Comment: @mplungjan No I am not able to reproduce like a normal user would go through the journey.

Comment: Then the way is to store a token and see if that token already is in the database and update the content if it is from the same interaction

Comment: working jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 submit buttons so that means whenever you click on any of these button, form will be submitted. You should use only one submit button.

Use other buttons for interaction on the page only.

Only one `type="submit"` button should be in your form. Remove `type="submit"` from rest three buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the buttons doesn't prevent the form from being submitted; it's the *form* being submitted, not the buttons. Use `preventDefault` in the `submit` handler instead:

```
$("#ques_response").submit(function(e){
  // if you want to prevent the form submission that was just triggered from being submitted for real:
  e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: But only if needed

Comment: This doesn't submit the form at all, not even for the first time.